# Flip animation in Android for a Fragment transaction setting a "z" index or a camera

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I'm trying to animate transaction between two fragments, with this code:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

But the result is exactly this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_card_flip.mp4

However, I want this result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52mXHqX9f3Y

The difference, is that even tho both rotate 180º, the second one does it with a different camera (Z-Axis).

So the question is:

- Can I apply a Z-Index to object animators?
- Or, can I provide an Animation class instead of a XML file containing an animation to animate fragment transitions?

Thanks.

Edit: Check differences.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use the code on github that he references in that YouTube clip? http://genzeb.github.io/flip/

Comment: It's using an Animation object, which I cannot use AFAIK with fragment transitions

Comment: Its hard to explain. The moment when the view is flipping, is captured on those two images. On the left: example in this post's answer. On the right, the iOS animation. As you can see the left angles never go as deep as iOS example does.

Comment: Check the youtube link on a below answer please

Comment: aha - you should put links like that into your question rather - it would make it much easier to follow. Good luck, I look forward to reading a's final solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to do two more things in your animators:

- rotate the view using a pivot that is not the default one (placed in the middle of the view)
- translate the view while rotating

In both cases you need to know the size of your view, so I would recommend to create your custom layout component to be used as root of your fragments, exposing a set of properties you can animate using different `objectanimator` inside your xml.

The component should look like this:

```
public class FlippableLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private FlipEvaluator flipRightInEvaluator;
    private FlipEvaluator flipRightOutEvaluator;
    private FlipEvaluator flipLeftInEvaluator;
    private FlipEvaluator flipLeftOutEvaluator;

    public FlippableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FlippableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setCameraDistance(getCameraDistance() * 10); // reduces perspective skewing
        flipRightInEvaluator = new FlipEvaluator(
                1f, .5f, // pivotX/pivotY
                -1f, 0f, // translationX start/end
                -180, 0, // rotationY start/end
                0f, 1f); // alpha start/end
        flipRightOutEvaluator = new FlipEvaluator(
                0f, .5f,
                0f, 1f,
                0, 180,
                1f, 0f);
        flipLeftInEvaluator = new FlipEvaluator(
                .0f, .5f,
                1f, 0f,
                180, 0,
                0f, 1f);
        flipLeftOutEvaluator = new FlipEvaluator(
                1f, .5f,
                0f, -1f,
                0, -180,
                1f, 0f);
    }

    public void setFlipRightIn(float value) {
        evaluateUsing(flipRightInEvaluator, value);
    }

    public void setFlipRightOut(float value) {
        evaluateUsing(flipRightOutEvaluator, value);
    }

    public void setFlipLeftIn(float value) {
        evaluateUsing(flipLeftInEvaluator, value);
    }

    public void setFlipLeftOut(float value) {
        evaluateUsing(flipLeftOutEvaluator, value);
    }

    private void evaluateUsing(FlipEvaluator evaluator, float value) {
        float cappedValue = Math.min(1f, Math.max(0f, value));
        setPivotX(getWidth() * evaluator.getPivotX());
        setPivotY(getHeight() * evaluator.getPivotY());
        setAlpha(evaluator.getAlpha(cappedValue));
        setTranslationX(getWidth() * evaluator.getTranslationX(cappedValue));
        setRotationY(evaluator.getRotationY(cappedValue));
    }

    private static class FlipEvaluator {
        private final float pivotX;
        private final float pivotY;
        private final float startTranslationX;
        private final float endTranslationY;
        private final float startRotationY;
        private final float endRotationY;
        private final float startAlpha;
        private final float endAlpha;

        /**
         * Simple evaluator holding all the start/end values for a flip animation.
         *
         * @param pivotX value between 0 and 1, where 0 is the left border and 1 is the right border of the target
         * @param pivotY value between 0 and 1, where 0 is the top border and 1 is the bottom border of the target
         * @param startTranslationX value between 0 and 1, where 1 is the width of the target
         * @param endTranslationY value between 0 and 1, where 1 is the width of the target
         * @param startRotationY value between -180 and 180
         * @param endRotationY value between -180 and 180
         * @param startAlpha initial alpha
         * @param endAlpha final alpha
         */
        private FlipEvaluator(float pivotX, float pivotY,
                              float startTranslationX, float endTranslationY,
                              float startRotationY, float endRotationY,
                              float startAlpha, float endAlpha) {
            this.pivotX = pivotX;
            this.pivotY = pivotY;
            this.startTranslationX = startTranslationX;
            this.endTranslationY = endTranslationY;
            this.startRotationY = startRotationY;
            this.endRotationY = endRotationY;
            this.startAlpha = startAlpha;
            this.endAlpha = endAlpha;
        }

        public float getPivotX() {
            return pivotX;
        }

        public float getPivotY() {
            return pivotY;
        }

        public float getTranslationX(float t) {
            return startTranslationX + (endTranslationY - startTranslationX) * t;
        }

        public float getRotationY(float t) {
            return startRotationY + (endRotationY - startRotationY) * t;
        }

        public float getAlpha(float t) {
            return t < .5f ? startAlpha : endAlpha;
        }

    }

}
```

Your animation files will look like this:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:propertyName="flipLeftIn"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="1000" />
```

Of course you can change `flipLeftIn` with `flipLeftOut`, `flipRightIn` or `flipRightOut` in order to apply the animator to a different property.

In your `Activity` you can set custom animations in your fragment transaction as usual, specifying the XMLs you previously defined:

```
    ....
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
    ....
```

[image: Flip example]

The other approach is to do everything in the XML, but setting the pivot/translation using a dimension value defined via XML is not as scalable as the solution shown above.

**EDIT**
To reduce the camera distance you can easily use [View.setCameraDistance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setCameraDistance(float)) on API>12. I updated the snippet including this change.

[image: Flip with less skewing]

Comment: Please, check my comment on the other answer.

Comment: I did, of course before starting to put my answer here. I checked the video linked below and the solution I posted provides the same effect shown at ~3:10. You can see that the vertical edge of the view is not "pushed" along Z like in Vikram's solution, but it stays on the edge of the viewport all the time. Probably you want to look better at the gif posted, and maybe trying the code yourself.

Comment: hello. It's fairly better, but please. Check my edit in the question. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. What you want is reducing the skewing effect caused by perspective. Unfortunately I had the same problem a while ago and didn't find any way to change the depth used by the `Camera` class. What I ended up with eventually was implementing the skewing my own using `Matrix` facilities. I will try to modify my solution to cope with this.

Comment: Turns out that there is a method to adjust the camera distance http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setCameraDistance(float) It's API 12+ tho. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Set camera distance is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow a.bertucci's answer but the animation doesn't work, I don't know why... I am a bit new to this world and a bit hard for me to understand what is going on about the custom FlippableFrameLayout.

But inspired by his answer on Camera distance, I found that I just need to impose one more animation on the scale property. (i.e. scaleX and scaleY)

Therefore, with **everything else the same as** [official tutorial here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html), you just need to modify the animator xml files to achieve the desired effect:

For **left_out.xml** and **right_out.xml**, **add** the following:

```
    <objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1f"
    android:valueTo="0.5f"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1f"
    android:valueTo="0.5f"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half" />
```

For **left_in.xml** and **right_in.xml**, **add** the following:

```
    <objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.5f"
    android:valueTo="1.0f"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half" />

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.5f"
    android:valueTo="1.0f"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half" />
```

And of course, you can modify the valueFrom and valueTo here (I used 0.5f), to adjust the "camera distance".